# can't clone repository from gcloud

Tags: git, authentication, credentials, gcloud

I need to clone a remote repository.I have git and gcloud both installed and in PATH.(I'm in win10)

I just followed the google first steps guide. Worked in Ubuntu, but I need it on Win10.

This is the message error:

```
gcloud source repos clone default C:\Users\XXX
git: 'credential-gcloud.sh' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com': XXXX
Password for 'https://XXXX@source.developers.google.com':
git: 'credential-gcloud.sh' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your OAuth token password; Note that generated google.com passwords are not compatible with private repositories
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Repository in [C:\Users\XXX] is misconfigured.
```

Been two days doing some several google reasearch with no solution.
Anyone could help me?

```
C:\Users\jadov\Desktop\Repositorios>git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
user.name=XXXXX
user.email=XXXXX5@gmail.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
credential.helper=gcloud.sh
remote.origin.url=https://source.developers.google.com/p/PROJECT_ID/r/default
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

If you installed google-cloud-sdk with homebrew, you may have overlooked the instructions (which is easy to do because they quickly scroll by followed by the SDK's self-update).

This gets git working with gcloud for me:

```
google-cloud-sdk is installed at /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk. Add your profile:

      for bash users
        source '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
        source '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'

      for zsh users
        source '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'
        source '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'

      for fish users
        set fish_user_paths /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin
        set -x MANPATH /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/help/man /usr/local/share/man /usr/share/man /opt/x11/share/man

        Run fish_update_completions to generate completions for fish based on the man pages
```

You may also want to reset the git configuration:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git config --global --add --path credential.helper gcloud
```

Comment: Just a comment for future reference, this fixed the error on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

Okai, solved it.

```
 git init
    Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/UsersXXXXXX/.git/
    cd .git
    gcloud init
    Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud....balbalbalbla
    gcloud source repos clone default default
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use gcloud.sh on windows credential.helper

change it use `git config credential.helper gcloud.cmd`